# view header are not visible when i scroll in Xpage View Panel

Tags: css, xpages, lotus-notes

I am facing a problem in xpage. I am showing 10000 documents in single page Using xpage view panel. When I use scroll , View headers also becomes invisible.

I got this link for the same query. They are asking to use extension library.
[This is the link where same query reported](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/0/a444b7ec6eeb939285257a3900737158?OpenDocument)

I can put my Scroll div for view panel only . is there any way to have scroll for view content only in xpage without Extension Library.?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The extension library gets installed with all current versions of Domino. It is fully IBM supported, so why not....

Anyway you asked:
On Dojomino there is an example how to read ?ReadViewEntries into a Dojo grid. It does roughly the same as the Extlib but with more steps.

.or. Use a repeat control and have non scrolling headers (afaik requires div not table - but you can google that, it is pure HTML/CSS)

Comment: Stwissel : Thanks for the info. I already suggested my customer to install Extension Library.But they is not needed extension library.  I will try Repeat control . will it be there any performance delay for repeat control compared to View panel ?

Comment: Performance delays are typically in the code WE write, not the one supplied by IBM. Suggest them to install the UpdatePack1, so the "we don't want unsupported components" discussion goes away. Showing 10000 documents in one go smells very much like an UI catastrophy